# Putting some values in bold in a DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to put some values in bold using the following function:

```
def highlight(x):
    return ['font-weight: bold' if v > 0.5 else ''
                for v in x]

Variable_Names =['FACTOR1','FACTOR2','FACTOR3'] 
rows = ['ECON1','ECON2','ECON2','FOOD1','FOOD2','FOOD3','ENV1','ENV2','HEA1', 'HEA2', 'HEA3','PERS1','PERS2','PERS3',
                 'COM1','COM2', 'POL1','POL2'] 
MatrixFactor = pd.DataFrame(fa.loadings_, index=rows, columns=Variable_Names)

print(MatrixFactor)
```

MatrixFactor output looks like this:

```
       FACTOR1   FACTOR2   FACTOR3
ECON1  0.882718 -0.384788 -0.268527
ECON2 -0.203138  0.840794  0.501013
ECON2  0.542073 -0.239280 -0.804945
FOOD1  0.931340  0.057863  0.358672
FOOD2  0.391803  0.413689  0.821324
FOOD3  0.277097  0.959034  0.048014
ENV1   0.997853  0.018340  0.057592
ENV2  -0.270908 -0.057319 -0.960368
```

The error I get when I run the following command:

```
display(MatrixFactor.reset_index().style.applymap(highlight))

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I am not sure what's going wrong here. When I try the highlight function on a different `dataframe`, it works fine.

Also tried `display(MatrixFactor.style.applymap(highlight))` but that gives this error:

```
ValueError: style is not supported for non-unique indices.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Styler.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) with select only numeric columns by `subset` parameter:

```
MatrixFactor.reset_index().style.apply(highlight, subset=Variable_Names)
```

Or change function for [`Styler.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.applymap.html):

```
def highlight(x):
    return 'font-weight: bold' if x > 0.5 else ''

MatrixFactor.reset_index().style.applymap(highlight, subset=Variable_Names)
```